# cosmosDB graph high RU usage even when limiting results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, graph-databases, gremlin-server, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a sample data that i modeled in my cosmos DB gremlin API. The sample csv is as follows

```
         Name,               Job Titles,             Department
"ADRIANO,  RACQUEL ANNE",    PARAMEDIC,              PARAMEDIC
"AFFANEH,  MAHIR A",         POLICE OFFICER,         POLICE
"AFOENYI,  PHYLLIS",         TITLE V,                PROGRAM TRAINEE I
"AGAR,  BULENT B",           DEPUTY COMMISSIONER,    WATER MGMNT
```

Each of these have additional metadata so i have modeled vertex typers `Employee`, `Job` and `Department`.

I am trying to run a query that gives me at most 20 of the police officers that have the `David` in their name. This is the query I am running.

`g.V().has('label', 'Employee').has('name', TextP.containing('DAVID')).as('a').outE('works_as').otherV().has('name', 'POLICE OFFICER').select('a').limit(20)`

This is consuming a lot of RUs even though i am only returning 20 of them. I have modified the query slightly to flip the query order to below, but this is performing worse RU wise.

`g.V().has('name', 'POLICE OFFICER').inE().outV().has('name', TextP.containing('DAVID')).limit(20)`

Is there anyway I can improve this query to cost me lower RUs?

Comment: I've not used the Gremlin API, but this kind of query would be very cheap through the SQL API. If there's not a specific reason to use a graph, it might be worth trying a more traditional modeling and the SQL API.

Comment: This is only a sample for test purposes. We do have a lot of hierarchical data and custom relationships between objects that is requiring us to use a graph and searching/filtering queries like these are required on  those.